# Search & Concatenate? Find A String and Concatenate Value From Adjacent Cell into "Master Cell"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-concatenation

Here's how Data is laid out:

**Company Ticket #**
Apple 123456
Bestbuy 121457
Target 123458
Apple 123479
Target 123446

I need to Find Every Ticket # for apple, and place into a cell, ex: (123456, 123479)

I'm thinking I can use some version of search and the concatenate function to accomplish this.  Have tried so far with no luck

Would prefer no VBA / pivot tables :)

Comment: no way - `CONCATENATE` does not work in array mode, so UDF only. There are many similar threads here, do search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra row to test it properly:

```
Company Ticket #
Apple   123456
Bestbuy 121457
Target  123458
Apple   123479
Target  123446
Apple   124
```

It's not very elegant but here goes:

In the last row (say row 7) in column C (C7):

`=B7`

In the row above in column C (C6): 
   `=IF(ISNA(INDEX($A$7:C7,MATCH(A6,$A$7:A7,0),3)),B6,INDEX($A$7:C7,MATCH(A6,$A$7:A7,0),3)&", "&B6)`

You have to do it backwards because match finds the first one going down that is a match.

Drag that formula up to the top row (C2).
The first row will of the company will have a list of all the ticket numbers separated by ", ":

```
Company Ticket  
Apple   123456  124, 123479, 123456
Bestbuy 121457  121457
Target  123458  123446, 123458
Apple   123479  124, 123479
Target  123446  123446
Apple   124 124
```

Comment: LIKE A BOSS!  You Rock!!  Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, unlike 99% of the others out here ... "what have you tried / do a search" ... Lol I do search before I come here .. thoroughly .. I could not put 2 and 2 together ... look at the forumla for pete's sake .. you have to have a solid understanding of many excel functions to piece this together...

Either be like Luke, provide a solution I can now study and LEARN .. or don't waste your breath with fluff / rude content trying to make someone feel stupid...

Thanks again Luke!!